# Shopify Ajax Update Cart

Tags: shopify

I want to be able to update my cart when I click on the increase button without having to click update button

Here is my script

```
<script>
  let classlist = []
  let val = document.querySelector('.qty-select')
  let classes = document.getElementsByClassName('val')
  for (var i=0; i<classes.length; i++) {
    classlist.push(classes[i].innerText)
  }
  let lineclasses = classlist.join(", ")
  val.onclick = function() {
    jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {updates: [lineclasses]});
    console.log('dfdfdfd')
  }
</script>
```

Here is my Liquid

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
<div class="product row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <img src="{{ item | img_url: 'medium' }}" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-7 product-info">
    <div class="product-title">
      {{ item.product.title }}
      <span class="price right"><b>{{ item.price | money }}</b></span>
    </div>
    <div class="qty-select">
      <input type="number" hidden="hidden" name="updates[]" id="updates_{{ item.key }}" class="qty"
        value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" />
      <span class="val">{{ item.quantity }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-1 col-sm-1 text-right remove">
    <a aria-label="Remove {{ item.variant.title }}"
      href="/cart/change?line={{ forloop.index }}&amp;quantity=0"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried this, but its not working

Comment: If you open your browser's dev tools and go to the "Network" tab, you should be able to see your post request to `/cart/update.js`. Clicking on your update request, you should be able to find the data that you're sending and should also be able to see whether Shopify responded with an error or an updated cart. Can you please verify what the data being posted is and what the response from Shopify is?

Comment: @DaveB, it sending the old data, it not taking the new value

Comment: Do you have any code running that updates the displayed value? It could just be that your two functions are firing out-of-order. If so, consolidating everything into a single function will probably help.  Also, is there any particular reason why you are preferring to use the `/cart/update.js` (which updates multiple lines) rather than the `/cart/change.js` endpoint (which only updates a single line)?

Comment: I don't have two functions, just one

Comment: I'm confused then with respect to how your snippet is set up, sorry. Which element is the 'increase' button and what all is happening when you click on it currently? I see that you're just reading the innerText of some element to get the current value, but I don't see anything that is updating that value.